# Unable to create web application archive: No such file or directory

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, tomcat

I have an application that I m trying to deply it on Tomcat. However, I keep getting this error:

```
Could not publish to the server.
Unable to create web application archive: No such file or directory
```

So If I get it right, thing is that WAR cannot be created cause of lack of permissions to create in the specified directory, is that right?

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you that the location where you intend to deploy to does not exist. If that is the case, you need to create that location.

Now, if you have that location, then you need to make sure that the OS user which makes the deployment has write permissions on the location. This is well documented and the solution highly depends on the operating system of your server.

Comment: Hi Lajos, I indent to deploy on Amazon ElasticBeanstalk using the AWS plugin for eclipse. Any experience with AWS?